# Subclass EditText to add Labels

Tags: android, android-edittext

I wrote a simple subclass to add labels to edittext fields.  I want to have a label in addition to a hint.  The field should be editable, have a hint on the righthand side of the field, and have a label on the lefthand side of the box.

```
  @Override
  public void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (labelX == -1 || labelY == -1) {
      makeTextMeasurements();
    }
    canvas.save();
    canvas.drawText(mLabel, labelX, labelY, mPaint);
    canvas.restore();
  }

  private void makeTextMeasurements() {
    mMeasuredTextHeight = getTextHeight(mPaint);
    labelX = (int) ViewUtils.getScaledPixels(20, getContext());
    labelY = (int) ((getHeight() / 2.0f) + (mMeasuredTextHeight / 2.0f));
  }
```

The class works fine if I do not call setInputType.  But if I call setInputType, the text that is to be drawn by canvas.drawText() does not appear.  I looked through the EditText source code but couldn't find a reason for why this is happening.  Anyone have ideas?